# Layout switch shortcuts keys prevent me from using the same combination

Tags: xorg, keyboard-shortcuts

Installed everything using graphics expert install, using MATE as my default DE. I use CTRL+SHIFT to switch my language. But I can't use these hotkeys in system anywhere else. I.E. if I try to make MATE system monitor to show up by CTRL+SHIFT+ESC - I either can do only CTRL+ESC or SHIFT+ESC. Same with terminal copy paste.

So one solution I have is just to use different language switch hotkey (ALT+SHIFT or something like that). But I do believe that is not a true solution.

Googled it, here also - no matching answers.

Comment: Just select a less-likely-to-shadow-something-else key combination for switching languages.

Comment: that will work, but CTRL+SHIFT worked in ubuntu for language switch AND anything alse

Comment: @Anthon, also it would be very confusing having to deal with different keyboard shortcuts for the same goal on different distributions :(

Comment: @GBarkhatov, have you resolved this ?